# Restart a computer at a given time with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, reboot, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

I'm looking for a way to restart a computer with PowerShell (`Restart-Computer`), at a given time (Example: 03:00AM). The PS-Script itself will run at a random time, when the user executes it, so it's no option to schedule the script at 03:00AM.

My first thought was to schedule a task, at 03:00AM (with PowerShell) that will execute the reboot for me.  This is possible (I think) with `New-ScheduledTask` in PowerShell 4.0. The downside is that I'm not sure if the computers that will run this script have PowerShell 4.0.

Is it possible to schedule a task with PowerShell 2.0, or is there another way to reboot the computer at a given time?

Thank you

Comment: you can use schtasks.exe to schedule a task - from any (power)shell.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you trying to *create* the task using Powershell? That's what `New-ScheduledTask` is for. If you're just looking to set up a scheduled reboot, Scheduled Tasks (the GUI) is going to be your friend here.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to schedule a reboot, with Powershell. New-ScheduledTask is only for PowerShell 4.0. I'm going to try Boboes his approach, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could run

```
shutdown -r -t ([decimal]::round(((Get-Date).AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(3) - (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds))
```

This will get the number of seconds between the time the script is ran and 3:00AM the following day. It then passes the result to shutdown.exe. Obviously this is designed to be ran before midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following to run as a scheduled task:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Restart-Computer -Force
```

[image: Task configuration]